# WPF load background image on form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, background-image

Hey all I have the following code that *supposed* to take my jpg image and place it on the background of the form. However, all I see is a black background.

```
Dim myBrush As New ImageBrush()
Dim image As New Image()
Dim grid As New Grid()

image.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/1680-logoless.jpg"))
myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source
grid.Background = myBrush
```

[image]

And this is my current XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="157,145,0,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="335,62,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Encrypt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="335,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="toEncrypt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" Margin="335,145,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="toDecrypt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" Margin="335,173,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Decrypt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="335,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Anyone see anything I could be missing?

Comment: Did you set the Build Action of the image file to `Resource`?

Comment: @Clemens yes, yes I did.

Comment: And what is the Image control for? Just write `myBrush.ImageSource = New BitmapImage(...)` instead.

Comment: Also make sure that the file is actually in a folder named `Resources`  and that `WpfApplication1` actually is the name of the assembly that contains the image file resource. Or use the short version of the URI: `pack://application:,,,/Resources/1680-logoless.jpg`

Comment: @Clemens updated my OP to show the resources.

Comment: Ok, apparently you're setting the Background property of a new Grid instance, instead of one from your XAML. Or are you doing anything with the new Grid later?

Comment: @Clemens Made another update to the OP to show my XAML.

Comment: As a note, do not create your layout by setting element Margins. Instead, declare Grid rows and columns. Take a look at the online documentation of class Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `x:Name` attribute of the Grid in XAML, which will create a field in your MainWindow class:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then, instead of creating a new Grid instance, set the Background of the one declared in XAML:

```
rootGrid.Background = New ImageBrush(New BitmapImage(
    New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/1680-logoless.jpg")))
```

Comment: There it is! Thanks for the help, Clemens